# Can I insert a custom attribute into a HTML element using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

I want to add a custom attribute to an html tag using jQuery.

Here's what I'm starting with...

```
<div class="module media object">
```

And here's what I want to end up with ...

```
<div class="module media object reveal-modal" id="objectModal" data-reveal>
```

No problem adding the class and ID, but how can I add the "data-reveal"?

Is this possible? Any help appreciated... FYI, I'm new to jQuery.

Cheers, Arnold

Comment: How did you add the id?

Comment: $('div.object').attr('id', 'objectModal')

Comment: Hm.. a function that adds attributes to elements.. interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add it with (empty) value.

```
$('.module .media .object').attr("data-reveal", "");
```

Some browsers will even evaluate the empty value to exactly what you want (`data-reveal`). (I've seen it in Safari) Others will evaluate it to `data-reveal=""`, which is still a valid `true` as for all boolean attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `data()` method to achieve this:

```
$('.module').data('reveal', 'foo');
```

Note however that this will not appear in the markup, but is instead stored in an object which jQuery stores in memory. You can retrieve the value of the attribute using the `data()` getter:

```
var reveal = $('.module').data('reveal'); // == 'foo'
```

Answer (score 0):

Certainly. Simply use the [jQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) function. It supports HTML5-style data attributes.

```
$('#objectModal').data('reveal', true);
```

This would assign the value "true", and would be an attribute called "data-reveal" on the element now. Similarly, you can use the same function as a getter.

```
var foo = $('#objectModal').data('reveal');
```

Comment: `$('#objectModal').data('reveal', true);` will **not** add an attribute to the element.

Comment: @JasonP My mistake, you are correct. I forgot it is simply an object stored on the element. I must have mixed that up since jQuery can access data attributes that are already on the element through the `data()` method still.